# What happens to Colombian beans that do not make Supremo or Extra?

Tags: growing, farming

I'm learning about Colombian coffee and its [national grading standards](http://www.coffeereview.com/coffee-reference/coffee-categories/geographic-origins/coffees-from-the-americas/colombia/) of Supremo (highest) and Extra (second highest). Does anyone know what percentage of all beans produced falls into those two categories? What happens to the beans that don't make one of those two grades?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They get sold for less money as "standard export" grade coffee.  Because of NFC's marketing campaign, ANY sort of Colombian coffee ends up with higher brand recollection than most other coffee.  There is a slightly slanted view of the matter [here](https://www.sweetmarias.com/library/content/colombia-0).  The writers are coffee aficionados who prize distinctive origin flavors in their coffee, which is rarely present in NFC graded coffee since they are more often than not mixed batches of beans from different growers.  That isn't to say that the NFC's work doesn't ensure high standards for Colombian exports, but it isn't favorable to some sectors of the coffee market who prize distinct coffee from a single origin. 
[image]

Comment: Cool thanks! Your picture does indeed speak a thousand words. In your link, I was surprised to read that the Supremo and Extra grades are not about quality but about bean size.

Comment: There is a lot of variation in the coffee market.  Lots of beans that look uniform will sell better to some customer segments than beans with size and shape irregularities (peaberries left in) and a higher cupping score.